# External integration with DAM (OTMM)

Tags: external-integrations

Please suggest a best way to integrate with Open Text media manager  if anybody have worked?

Thanks
Tapan Vaidya

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite broad, and not very clear.
It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

However, the most obvious way to integrate an external system in your Tridion environment is by using ECL (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-6127E254-2754-41E0-992C-5ADF18296775)

Using this ECL api, you are able to write any kind of provider that will make content from an external system available to your SDL Web/Tridion editors